# What are $n$-body potentials, and $n$-body correlation functions?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions

In studying statistical mechanics, we ran into the concept of 3-body potentials, and in general $n$-body potentials. For $N$ interacting spherical particles in a closed volume $V$ in $d$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Let $\Phi _N(r^N)$ be the N-body potential for particles with configuration $r^N=r_1,r_2,r_3,...$
$$\Phi_N (r^N) = \sum_{i=1}^N \phi(r_i) + \sum _{i<j} \phi _2 (r_i, r_j) + \sum _{i<j}\sum _{j<k} \phi (r_i,r_j,r_k)$$

What are these 3-body potentials? They are obviously not a sum of 2-body potentials because then we wouldn't have a separate term for them.

Kind of in the same vein, I think, we define $g_n(r)$ as the $n$-particle correlation function. $g_2(r)$ makes sense to me, as it is the probability of finding a particle in a hollow shell at a distance $r$ with a thickness $dr$. How do you think about $g_3(r)$?